# How to get a border at the bottom of my toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I want to add a gray border at the bottom of my white toolbar so that it's distinctly separated from the main content. I'm setting up my toolbar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/pick_root_layout">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/pick_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar.White"
    android:background="@color/white">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/conversation_list">
  </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to add a small gray line at the bottom of the toolbar that also scrolls with it when I move. How can I do this? I'd like to avoid making a custom layout if possible.

Comment: It sounds like you want a drop shadow type effect on the toolbar that will stay attached to the toolbar when you scroll the list view, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a drop shadow type effect that will stay attached to the toolbar an easy way to get this is to wrap your SwipeRefreshLayout with a FrameLayout and place a foreground on the FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/pick_root_layout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/pick_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar.White"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="@drawable/bottom_shadow">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ListView
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:id="@+id/conversation_list" />

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Shadow 9 patch -> [image: bottom_shadow.9.png]